# Vimeo: how to set privacy for video to use video in a mobile app?

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api, vimeo-android, vimeo-ios

The are the privacy related settings actually available

```
privacy.download    Whether people can download the video   true | false
privacy.embed       Where the video can be embedded         private | public | whitelist*
privacy.view        Who can view the video on Vimeo         anybody | contacts | disable | nobody | password | unlisted | users*
```

I wany my video be unlisted on vimeo, ok. It's `privacy.view` to set as `unlisted`.

But If I want that our official app can browse and play these videos, how must I set `privacy.embed` and / or `privacy.download`?

I'd like to use whitelist, because our mobile app will have a companion webapp and so I've the domain(s) to enable. But using whitelist, can I still play them in a mobile app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Domain-level privacy cannot be used for videos that are intended for viewing within a native mobile app. Because there is no domain name or HTTP referer associated with a native application, the Player cannot determine if the video is allowed to be played from the location where it is embedded.

Comment: Thanks. So 'embed' is not related to embedding via html player but is relevant regarding the ip of the client that is viewing a video? If it's right, the name 'embed' is fuorviant

Comment: Vimeo's embed settings are related to the iframe embed code and is intended for embedding on a webpage when viewed within a web browser. Embedding a Vimeo Player using an in-app browser or webview may work, but it's not a usecase explicitly supported by Vimeo.

Comment: I can now confirm that private video will work both embedding player on a domain in the whitelist, and also using a custom player using the private link. So private and whitelist options can be combined

Comment: @realtebo do you mean if I set Domain-level privacy, I can still play the vimeo video from mobile app using lightbox linked to the video url? I thought that wasn't possible since the origin in mobile apps are like localhost or something. Can you confirm that please?

Comment: Yes, I can confirm. This is due to fact that the url itself is made private, but you can anyway see video if you have the url. Is the url is called from webplayer embedded in a website, the webplayer check domain level privacy. But from webapp, no domain-level check are executed. We are actually using this combination of config in production.